# listview bind to object of class wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, togglebutton

I have the following `AddedInfo` class:

```
public class AddedInfo : ViewModelBase
{
    private string m_infoString = "ppp";
    private ToggleButton m_infoButton = new ToggleButton();

    #region Properties

    public string InfoString
    {
        get { return m_infoString; }
        set
        {
            m_infoString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ToggleButton InfoButton
    {
        get { return m_infoButton; }
        set
        {
            m_infoButton = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties
}
```

In my `ViewModel`, I have the following definition:

```
private ObservableCollection<AddedInfo> m_informationList = new ObservableCollection<AddedInfo>();

public ObservableCollection<AddedInfo> InformationList
{
    get { return m_informationList; }
    set
    {
        m_informationList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And in the `Xaml`:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding InformationList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

I would like the `ListView` to show only the `ToggleButtons` from class `AddedInfo` (meaning the `InfoButton` object).

Can such thing be done?

Comment: No, this is bad. Do not ever, ever, ever make a UI control a property of a viewmodel. It is much easier and better to use DataTemplates to create controls. Expose a boolean property and *bind* it to the `IsChecked` property of a `ToggleButtton` created in a template by the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ItemTemplate](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) for the ListView. You did not provide details about the ToggleButton class, but it should not be a control. In MVVM the viewmodels and models should contain only data. The control can be rendered in the view using DataTemplates (as ItemTemplate contains a DataTemplate).